# Print Large image over multiple pages in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I want to print large images (in height) in pdf using Itextsharp (in c#.net).
when I try to print any image which is larger (in height) than the page size, then the itextsharp would abort the printing and print the message like: "Infinite Table Loop".

I want to print the large image over multiple pages.

Anyone would share their ideas and experience would be much helpful.

Thanks

Dilip Patel

Comment: Why are you adding the image inside a table? Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Table functionality has dramatically improved over the years; please don't expect an answer if you're using an obsolete version of iTextSharp.

Comment: Are you trying to _tile_ a single large image across multiple PDF pages? If so, you need to manually slice the image up (very easy to do in .Net) and add those individual images to individual PDF pages.